# Matlab converting symbolic variable into array

Tags: matlab, symbols, symbolic-math

I want to convert a function that is defined in terms of a symbolic variable `x` into an array. My MWE is:

```
syms x
f = x.^2;
x = linspace(-10,10,100);
f1 = double(f);
```

I tried to use the `double` command, but get an error

```
Error using symengine
Unable to convert expression into double array.

Error in sym/double (line 692)
        Xstr = mupadmex('symobj::double', S.s, 0);
```

I'm not sure what this means and how to resolve it.

Comment: try `f1 = double(f(x))`?

Comment: I can't test it here, but try `syms f(x); f1 = double(f(linspace(-10,10,100)))`?

Comment: I get an error: `Error using symengine. Unable to convert expression into double array. Error in sym/double (line 692).  Xstr = mupadmex('symobj::double', S.s, 0);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Replace `x` by its given values before applying `double()` using
  `subs()`
- `vpa()` has a similar function
- The advantage using `vpa()` compared to `double()` is that you can set
  the decimal precision by yourself

**The code is as follows**

```
syms x
f = x.^2;
x = linspace(-10,10,10);
f1 = subs(f);
f2 = double(f1)
f3 = vpa(f1, 8)
```

---

- `double()` output: ***fixed number of digits after decimal point***

```
f2 = [100.0000   60.4938   30.8642   11.1111    1.2346    1.2346   11.1111   
30.8642   60.4938  100.0000]
```

---

- `vpa()` output: ***adjustable number of digits after decimal point***, here precision adjusted to 8

```
f3 =[ 100.0, 60.493827, 30.864198, 11.111111, 1.2345679, 1.2345679, 11.111111, 
30.864198, 60.493827, 100.0]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this. Starting with [`symfun`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/symfun.html):

```
syms x
f = symfun(x.^2, x);
xv = linspace(-10,10,100);
f1 = double(f(xv));
```

This is equivalent to:

```
syms x       % or: syms f(x)
f(x) = x.^2;
xv = linspace(-10,10,100);
f1 = double(f(xv));
```

Alternative is using the `subs` approach as suggested by [Adam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11175375/adam).